# Pass value from textbox in view to controller method and get a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Inside my Index view I have a search bar and a button. I want to get the value from the search bar and call a new method from Home Controller called SearchResults, and pass in the value from the search bar. SearchResults woudl then return a new view with a model that I can display the data retrieved by the query.

I've looked everywhere and cannot find a satisfactory answer. I've tried using jquery but it doesn't appear to work because it only keeps me on the same page, and I need to return a new view. I have no model in Index because I just need the info from the search bar and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like below. Since, you have not provided any sample code, I am assuming you have an input element of type text for the search textbox and an input element of type button for the search button.

In code sample below,

1. `txtSearch` is the id of textbox used for inputting search string
2. `btnSearch` is the id of button used to call a specific controller/action
3. In C# code, you are getting `searchText` as the value of search textbox (note that the query string parameter searchText should be same as parameter name in the Action you are calling) and then returning any suitable view you want by just specifying its path in `View` method.

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" />

<input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch"
onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")?searchText=' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value; return false;" />
```

**Action C# code**

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchText = "")
{
  //TO DO???? do your search processing

   return View("~/Views/Folder1/Folder2/SomeView.cshtml")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST to an action on the controller, you can do this by setting the form action and method.

```
[HTTPPost]
Public ActionResult testpost(string search){}
```

Make sure the form field is named the same as the parameter in the method.